# geolocator - App crashes when asking for permission

Tags: flutter, permissions, geolocator

When I request permission to access the location, the program crashes.
I searched a lot, but I did not find a neat solution.
any solution?

the code:

```
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;

    permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.requestPermission();
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(Exception(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.'));
    }

    // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
    // continue accessing the position of the device.
    return await _geolocatorPlatform.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```

my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

when crash:

> D/AndroidRuntime(12834): Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834): Process: com.example.tracker, PID: 12834
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=109, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.tracker/com.example.tracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5453)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5492)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2282)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8250)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:430)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:272)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.SmsMethodCallHandler.execute(SmsMethodCallHandler.kt:169)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.SmsMethodCallHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(SmsMethodCallHandler.kt:378)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:777)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:409)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:757)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragment.java:915)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragmentActivity.java:549)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8781)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8634)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5446)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12834):    ... 13 more
> D/OOMEventManagerFK(12834): checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0
> I/Process (12834): Sending signal. PID: 12834 SIG: 9
> Lost connection to device.

Comment: Some people said that external storage permission should be requested, but I request for that too, the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```dart
      Future<Position> _determinePosition()  async {
            bool serviceEnabled;
            LocationPermission permission;
        // Test if Location services are enabled.
            serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
            if (!serviceEnabled) {
              // Location services are not enabled don't continue
              // accessing the position and request users of the
              // App to enable the Location services.
              await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
              return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
            }
        
            permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
        
            if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
              await Geolocator.requestPermission();
              if (permission != LocationPermission.denied) {
                // Location services are not enabled don't continue
                // accessing the position and request users of the
                // App to enable the Location services.
                return Future.error('Location permissions are disabled.');
              }
            }
            if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
              return Future.error('Location permissions are disabled permanently.');
            }
            return await _geolocatorPlatform.getCurrentPosition();
          }
```

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, it did not work.
But when I removed `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` the problem was solved.

Comment: You should use a permission handler too https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed these steps for the geolocator library.

1.**At first setup build.gradle->**[image]

2. also add ->

   android{

   ...

   configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.gms:play-
   services-location:20.0.0'
   }
   }[image]

3.For my case I have downgraded the library to [geolocator:^8.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/changelog).

4.Now finally I got my lat lng without crashing my app perfectly
this way-

```
final geo.Position position = await 
geo.Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
geo.LocationAccuracy.high);
  lat = position.latitude;
  lng = position.longitude;
```